# Trying to style a widget using gtkrc is not working - Zim wiki on Windows 7

Tags: gtk

I am using Zim wiki on Windows 7 and would like to style the pageview background to be a tiled bitmap. To start with, I am trying to see if I can just change the text colors.

I know the gtkrc is being correctly loaded because if I change the theme name, it is reflected when I start the application.

However if I try to apply a style as mentioned on http://zim-wiki.org/manual/Help/Config_Files.html

the style does not get applied. Is there something basic I am missing out?

```
gtk-theme-name = "MS-Windows"

style "mycolors" 
{
    base: "#333333"
    text: "#444444"
}

widget "*.zim-pageview" style "mycolors"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax given by the Config_File manual does not work for me either.

However I have tried the following syntax and it works for

```
pixmap_path "/path-to-background-image-files"

style "mycolors" 
{
  base[NORMAL]   = "black"
  base[SELECTED] = "#6699cc"   # npp deep black
  text[NORMAL]   = "#c0c0c0"   # windows cmd default color
  bg_pixmap[NORMAL] = "nexus.png"
}

widget "*.zim-pageview" style "mycolors"
widget "*.zim-pageindex" style "mycolors"
class "GtkWidget" style "mycolors"
```

I have referenced this link: [Silas S. Brown's .gtkrc file](http://people.ds.cam.ac.uk/ssb22/setup/_gtkrc.txt?/.gtkrc), and for bg_pixmap, I referenced this one: [pixmap sample](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit.cgi/matchbox-history/plain/matchbox-themes-extra/expose/gtk-2.0/gtkrc)

Comment: I figured it out and am using base[NORMAL] = "#fffadf"
 text[NORMAL] = "#8b4513" - which gives walnut colored text on the cream background used by OneNote. However, I have been unable to find a way to change the background to a tiled pixmap.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your original purpose... I will update my answer if I figure out a way to make Zim have a **tiled bitmap background**.

Comment: I have updated my answer, and the key lines are **pixmap_path,... bg_pixmap[..., and class "GtkWidget...**, which just proves that tiled pixmap does work.

Comment: It is not working for me :( I tried keeping the image in the etc/gtk-2.0 folder and using bg_pixmap[NORMAL] = "paper.png", and that prevented from the entire style being applied, I then also tried with bg_pixmap[NORMAL] = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Zim Desktop Wiki\etc\gtk-2.0\paper.png" which did not work either. What could be going wrong?

Comment: Fixed that. It was a problem with a non-standard space character in the pixmap line. Now am getting the pixmap as the background of everything but the pageview and pageindex http://imgur.com/3LbQF0d. How do I get the pixmap as the background of the pageview?

Comment: The devil is in the detail: I just had to replace all the `:` with `=` :-P